# Undefined method error using smarter_csv in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I am looking to find a relatively quick way to import data from a CSV file into a `sqlite3` database, having identified `smarter_csv` as a likely candidate I am having difficulties in applying their methodology for importing data in batches.

I have two versions, a first (basic version) which works and a second which currently produces the error `undefined method 'collection' for class`.

The first method imports everything from the csv file a row at a time and works successfully:

```
  f = File.open("newdata.csv", "r:bom|utf-8")
  templist = SmarterCSV.process(f) do |row|
        Alldata.create( row.first )
  end
  f.close
```

However, when I attempt to do this process in chunks instead I get the problem i mentioned above.  My code is currently:

```
  f = File.open("newdata.csv", "r:bom|utf-8")
  templist = SmarterCSV.process(f,{:chunk_size => 2}) do |chunk|
    Alldata.collection.insert( chunk )
  end
  f.close
```

I am pretty new to Rails in general, so this could well be a very basic problem, but any advice and guidance would be fantastic

Comment: I think the key problem was that I hadn't defined a method called `collection` in the controller.  Changing `collection.insert` line to `Alldata.create(chunk)` removed the error and inserted all data, however, performance was identical to the first approach.  Currently looking into doing the import directly in `sqlite3` as opposed to through rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key problem was that I hadn't defined a method called `collection` in the controller.  Changing `collection.insert` line to `Alldata.create(chunk)` removed the error and inserted all data, however, performance was identical to the first approach.  Currently looking into doing the import directly in `sqlite3` as opposed to through rails as i believe the performance will be far better.

Doing this through `sqlite3 console` converted this from being an 8 hour process, to a 3 second one :)